# How to Display data in a label from database only if today date matches the date for that record

Tags: c#, date, webforms, label

I have this table called EVENT_ANNOUNCE. Currently I only know how to display every data from the database which is the EVENTNAME column field into the 3 labels. I only want to have maximum 3 events on the form so I created 3 labels, one label for each record.

But I want to display the data only if today date matches the date for that record. Since today date is 31/03/2014, only record 1 and 2 should display only because record 1 is 31/03/2014 to 01/04/2014 and record 2 is 31/03/2014 to 31/03/2014.

[image]

[image]

**If i make 4 records that have today's date. The third label doesn't come out anything. I still will want the label 3 to display IT fair at Atrium tho. If I make 3 records that have today's date(that means without the fourth record which is test). those 3 labels will display as respectively Sales at Cheers, 50% all item and IT fair at Atrium no problem.**

[image]

[image]

```
public partial class number2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
    con.Open();
    str = "select * from EVENT_ANNOUNCE";
    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Read();
    lblEvent1.Text = reader["EVENTNAME"].ToString();
    reader.Read();

    lblEvent2.Text = reader["EVENTNAME"].ToString();
    reader.Read();

    lblEvent3.Text = reader["EVENTNAME"].ToString();
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the records by the current date. This should only get records where the current date falls within the start / end date range.

```
select * from EVENT_ANNOUNCE
where getdate() >= STARTDATE
  and cast(getdate() as Date) <= ENDDATE
```

The time portion of your `startdate` and `enddate` values is `00:00:00.000`, so using current date to filter results will not return the second record, unless you happen to run this at *exactly* midnight, down to the millisecond.

So call `cast` to drop the time portion of the current date, and that should get you both records.

---

Also, to avoid errors if your query returns no records, make use of the `HasRows` property:

```
var events = new List<string>();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
        events.Add(reader["EVENTNAME"].ToString());
}

if (events.Count >= 1)
    lblEvent1.Text = events[0];
if (events.Count >= 2)
    lblEvent2.Text = events[1];
if (events.Count == 3)
    lblEvent3.Text = events[2];
```

Comment: Erm, I should write that as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? Where does that comes from. Is that a code that represent today date? @Grant Winney

Comment: I tried either using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and GETDATE() using the right Click new query on server explorer. It came out only record 1. shouldn't it came out record 2 too? I added the image. And can help me replace to while (reader.HasRows) and show me the code as I have errors doing it. @Grant Winney

Comment: Thanks, it return me two records now. I left with the invalid to read when no data is present error. can help me replace to while (reader.HasRows) and show me the code as I have errors doing it. @Grant Winney

Comment: I got error. added the image. Because only two records that will be displayed for today, so there is error for the third label code. But there will be days that will have 3 events for the day so I need to have that third label and the code. @Grant Winney

Comment: Record 1 doesn't come out on label 1. added image  @Grant Winney

Comment: Thanks it worked, almost done, left this little problem i guess. I test it out with 4 records with today's date. See above post. @Grant Winney